# ¿como agrupar la cantidad facturada por divisa (currency rate) y por mes?

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select sh.CurrencyRateID, cr.ToCurrencyCode, 
       sum(TotalDue) as [cantidad facturada], month(OrderDate) as mes
from sales.SalesOrderHeader sh 
     join sales.CurrencyRate cr 
         on sh.CurrencyRateID=cr.CurrencyRateID
group by sh.CurrencyRateID, cr.ToCurrencyCode, month(OrderDate)
order by sh.CurrencyRateID asc, 2 desc, 4
```

La salida es la siguiente,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero ahora no se como agrupar el tipo de moneda,para que solo salga una vez,  y muestre el total

Comment: ¿a que te refieres con "solo salga una a la vez"?

Comment: por ejemplo en el registro 1,4,5,8 aparece AUD, como agrupar para que sume la cantidad facturada, y aparezca AUD solo una vez en vez de varias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sucede por que el agrupamiento se da **por todas las columnas del GROUP BY** y en consecuencia como la columna `CurrencyRateID` tiene 4 valores diferentes para el valor `AUD` de la columna `ToCurrencyCode`, se separa en estos 4 "sub grupos"

Simplemente debes eliminar del agrupamiento a la columna `CurrencyRateID`

```
SELECT cr.ToCurrencyCode, 
       SUM(TotalDue) as [cantidad facturada], 
       MONTH(OrderDate) as mes
   FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader sh 
       JOIN sales.CurrencyRate cr 
            ON sh.CurrencyRateID = cr.CurrencyRateID
   GROUP BY cr.ToCurrencyCode, MONTH(OrderDate)
```

Si también quieres eliminar la columna de mes, puedes hacer dos cosas.

Uno, eliminar `MONTH(OrderDate)` del GROUP BY y el SELECT, con lo que tendrás la suma total de todos los meses.

La otra es filtrar por un mes especifico y tendrás las suma total de un mes dado; Esto es opcional, eliminado la linea del WHERE alanza para obtener el total histórico.

```
SELECT cr.ToCurrencyCode, 
       SUM(TotalDue) as [cantidad facturada]
   FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader sh 
       JOIN sales.CurrencyRate cr 
            ON sh.CurrencyRateID = cr.CurrencyRateID
   WHERE MONTH(OderDate) = 7
   GROUP BY cr.ToCurrencyCode
```

Comment: ok, ya entendi ese punto de los subgrupos tienes razon ,pero sigue el problema ...

Comment: @m3nt0r1337 fijate que edite mi respuesta, espero que te ayude. Saludos!